# WebDriverException: Message: disconnected: not connected to DevTools [Python, macOs M2]

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to run tests using Chromedriver on MacBook M2, but I'm running into issues with Chrome and Chromedriver crashing. The browser window opens for a few seconds before crashing, and then this happen:

```
Stacktrace:

pages/base_page.py:90: in view
    self.driver.get(self.rel_url)

E       selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: cannot determine loading status
E       from disconnected: Unable to receive message from renderer
E         (Session info: chrome=111.0.5563.64)

/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py:242: WebDriverException


INTERNALERROR> selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: disconnected: not connected to DevTools
INTERNALERROR>   (failed to check if window was closed: disconnected: not connected to DevTools)
INTERNALERROR>   (Session info: chrome=111.0.5563.64)
```

it crashes on clicks, get() etc. not only the one exact place.

environment:

Python 3.11 installed with Brew,
macOS Ventura 13.2.1 M2,
Chrome version 111.0.5563.64,
Chromedriver version: 111.0.5563.64, installed in /usr/local/bin/chromedriver

I've tried the following steps to resolve the issue, but none of them have worked:

Upgrading to the latest version of Chrome and Chromedriver, reinstalling both Chrome and Chromedriver, provide brew's chromedriver path

In headless it works fine

Here are the options:

```
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-notifications')
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
chrome_options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
chrome_options.add_argument('--hide-scrollbars')
```

i'm not providing the chromedriver path since the browser starts and opens a page without a problem:
webdriver.Chrome(desired_capabilities=capabilities)

Comment: Seems v111 makes this.

Comment: that's what I think. actually it stopped crashing (from time to time) on the next day - very unstable. also, I observed it stops crashing right after headless launch

Comment: After hibernate, it happens for me.

Comment: I started seeing very similar behavior.  Mac M2, python 3.11, chrome 112.0.5615.49.  I enabled chromedriver logging which didn't seem to tell me anything.  One moment we're waiting for `invisibility_of_element_located` the next devtools has disconnected.  It looks like chrome just up and quit.

Comment: What's really interesting is I don't seem to crash when I run headless using the old method.   `options.headless = True`

Comment: possible workaround is webdriver_manager